# como usar caracteres en una condicion "If"

Tags: c++

hola alguien me podria decir como hacer esta condicion condicion (Dia=="miercoles") es un programa que descuente entradas de cine si es dia miercoles pero no me funciona.

Comment: Agrega el código que haz tratado

Comment: Agrega toda la informacion relacionada con tu codigo. Que es dia por ejemplo? viene escrito como un dia asi? mira por favor [ask]

Comment: En lugar de preguntar aquí deberías leer un buen libro de C++.

Answer (score 3):

Si usas arrays de caracteres al estilo C tienes que usar una función que compare ambos arrays y devuelva el resultado de la comparación... las cadenas de caracteres no se pueden comparar directamente pero sí puedes verificar el resultado de una función:

```
char Dia[20] = /* ... */
if (strcmp(Dia, "miercoles") == 0)
{
  // ...
}
```

Aunque ya que estás en C++ puedes pasar a usar `std::string`. Esta clase dispone de su propio operador de comparación, con lo que puedes escribir de forma natural:

```
std::string Dia = "miercoles";
if( Dia == "miercoles" )
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar 2 cadenas de texto en c se utiliza el `strcmp`

Utilizarias algo asi:

```
if (strcmp(Dia, "miercoles") == 0) { /* descuenta las entradas de cine */ }
```

La función regresa 0 cuando las 2 cadenas son iguales

Answer (score -1):

Para comparar dos strings en c++ debes:

```
string a = "A";
string a = "B";

if(!a.compare(b))
   // Son iguales
else
   // No lo son
```

Comment: te falto un paréntesis, debería ser `if(!a.compare(b))`